# Displaying number_format variable without changing dir type

Tags: php, html, mysql, internationalization, right-to-left

When working with number_format to tables that contains arabic language and we used dir="rtl" to display table, and when applying number_format function I got this:
[image]

But what I really want is to apply the function and not changing the dir value.
Is their any help ?
What I want is to display 1 310 200,000 and not 000,200 310 1 without changing the dir or remove it.

Comment: Set the table cell where you're displaying this number as `dir="ltr"`